# zk viewmodel or selectorcomposer

Tags: zk

im newbie in zk´s world, so i have a doubt... i read already zk 8 documentation (almost all). At the office some partners are using ViewModel but inside some components are using Composer (selectorComposer) to bind some elements like this:

```
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.some.package.SomeViewModel')">
<vbox>
... SOME ANOTHER ELEMENTS ....
<div apply="com.some.package.SomeComposer">
<hbox>
<vbox>
    <checkbox  ... more code...
    </checkbox>
</vbox>
</hbox>
</div>
</vbox>
</div>
```

i read that if you apply SelectorComposer you lost coupling... so what is the reason of taking SelectComposer within a ViewModel? or how it works?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view `SelectComposer` allow you to reuse java code in a very traditional way. For example you can defined an `AbstractController` with functionality that will be reused in other controls of the same type with an slightly  different functionality and extend the `AbstractController`. In this approach you can control the lifecycle of the componente by implemented the methods of `SelectComposer` like `doAfterCompose`.
But actually you can do the same thing with pure MVVM, but instead of implement methods of `SelectComposer` you should use the annotations like `@AfterCompose` or `@Init` and you can extend the base class as well, to use your view you just have to change the tag in the zul file with something like:

```
<include src="/artifacts/componente_to_reuse.zul"/>
```

I think is just a matter of preferences, I preferred (and I always recommend) to use pure MVVM since it was available, and I haven't found any functionality that I couldn't reuse with MVVM approach.

References:
[Include](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/advanced/pass_arguments_to_include_component.html),
[Zk annotations](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/viewmodelinit.html)

Comment: Hello no_way, thank you very much for your answer, in fact i read that SelectorComposer becomes the patron MVVM to MVC because it creates a direct dependence on the UI components, also I thought that everything i do with SelectorComposer can do it using MVVM.

Anyway, seeing both combined patterns caused me some confusion, really thank you for the explanation.

By the way you speak Spanish?

Comment: @Mariah this paper http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/GUIPatterns_ZK_Java_Article_Final.pdf and its demo code does the same simple page as MVVM, MVC and MVVMP to show the trade offs between implementation of each approach. It is less about which feature of zk is used and more about what the developer is attempting to do with respect to the organisation and dependencies between the code.